# Watch OS app not able to connect with iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I am trying to connect my Watch OS app with iOS app and fetch some data but I am getting following error when I try to connect with iOS app:

> [WC] __28-[WCSession activateSession]_block_invoke_2 sessionReadyForInitialStateWithCompletionHandler failed due to NSXPCConnectionInterrupted
>
> __44-[WCSession updateApplicationContext:error:]_block_invoke failed due to WCErrorCodeSessionNotActivated
> WatchConnectivity session has not been activated.

iOS app Code:

```
- (void) startSession{
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    self.session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    self.session.delegate = self;
    [self.session activateSession];
}
```

}

Watch OS Code:

```
func startSession() {
    if(session.activationState != .activated){
        session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
}
public func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?){
    print("activationDidCompleteWith")
    if activationState == WCSessionActivationState.activated {
        NSLog("Activated")
        if(WCSession.default().isReachable){

            do {
                try session.updateApplicationContext(
                    [WatchRequestKey : "updateData"]
                )
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    if activationState == WCSessionActivationState.inactive {
        NSLog("Inactive")
    }
    
    if activationState == WCSessionActivationState.notActivated {
        NSLog("NotActivated")
    }
}
```

iOS app is in objective C and watch app is in swift

I execute my iOS app code first and it's delegate methods run but when I run watch os app it fails to execute any delegate method, and produce above error.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue with watchOS 2 and iOS app.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, were you able to figure out this problem. I am encountering the same error with iOS 13 and watchOS 6. My iOS app can session.updateApplicationContext() to the watch app fine. But from the watch app to iOS app, I get the 7018 error code. This happens in both simulators and physical devices. I have also cleaned the build folders and restarting computer.

Answer (score 1):

The `activate()` method runs [asynchronously](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615655-activate) from Watch OS v2.2 onwards. So, in your code, calling `updateApplicationContext` just after invoking `activate()` does not provide any guarantee that the session will be actually activated when trying to update the application context.

The correct flow would be to move your message to `session(_:activationDidCompleteWith:error:)`, as for example:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if activationState == .activated {
       // Update application context here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am now using it in delegate method but it is not being called, I am constantly getting error given above. session is not getting activated in watch os app although it gets activated in iPhone app.

Comment: @pankaj where do you call startSession() on the Watch?

Comment: I am calling it in willActivate() method of my interface